# Histogram "PDF" - Workaround for chopped y axis

Tags: options, histograms, workaround

My question is about finding a workaround and/or setting of parameters for a problem with the Histogram function and the "PDF" option.

This problem occurs when I use Mathematica (Wolfram Cloud Desktop v10.3.1.0) 1for creating a Histogram with the "PDF" option and the distribution is "narrow".

Basically, the leading zeros on the y-axis are chopped off and the result is a bit misleading.

Here are two examples that first shows the correct y-axis and then the chopped one.

A) Correct diagram

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 0.5], 2000];
Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF", PlotLabel -> "PDF"]
```

[image]

B) Misleading diagram

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 0.1], 2000];
Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF", PlotLabel -> "PDF"]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have a computer in front of me but that doesn't look wrong to me. Looks like it probably integrates to 1.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the comments. When I look at the PDF (Probability Density Diagram) on my computer and in the included diagram, the y value for e.g. 1 is 4, when it should be 0.4. Otherwise would the integral of the PDF be way bigger than 1.

Comment: Try the integration. You can integrate the PDF of HistogramDistribution to make that easier.

Comment: Why do you think the integral should be bigger than 1? The second distribution is far narrower, so the probability densities should indeed be larger. `DiscretePlot[Evaluate@CDF[HistogramDistribution[data], x], {x, 0.5, 1.5, .02}]` shows that the integral is correct.

Comment: @FredrikD - The height of the histogram bin is meaningless without considering the bin width. The contribution of a bin to the probability is the product of the bin height times the bin width, i.e., the area (integral) of the bin.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and Andy's answer. I see my mistake now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question will likely be closed as a simple mistake but here is what is going on. `HistogramDistribution` is equivalent to the "PDF" form of `Histogram`. It makes figuring out the properties of histograms easy.

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, .1], 2000];

dist = HistogramDistribution[data];
```

We can see that the PDF reaches somewhere near 4.

```
Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, .5, 1.5}, Filling -> Axis, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

We can integrate the PDF to verify that it is a proper PDF.

```
Integrate[PDF[dist, x], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]

(* 1. *)
```

For further validation, we can compare to the underlying distribution.

```
Plot[{PDF[NormalDistribution[1, .1], x], PDF[dist, x]}, {x, .5, 1.5}, 
 Filling -> Axis, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

It is common for people who are new to distributions to expect the PDF to reach no higher than 1. because text book examples typically show standard normal distributions, but this isn't the case here.